# merge worksheets that have drop-down list

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that consists of 180 worksheets. Each worksheet has the top 9 rows and columns A1:Z1 with information that I do not need.

The rest of the worksheet has data that I do need and want to append into one worksheet. The problem is that each of the worksheet has drop-down choices embedded in them. The choices have already been made and I need to append the sheets with the choices selected.

Been trying to run a VBA script but have been unsuccessful. Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Current code that I used to remove the top rows for few of the sheets, only removal but not appending. And I have inserted sheet names, but with 180 sheets that will not be possible.

`Sub remove_rows()`
'
' `remove_rows Macro`
'

'

```
`Rows("1:10").Select`
`Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False`
`Range("D20").Select`
`Rows("1:9").Select`
`Range("A9").Activate`
`Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp`
`Sheets("BioME-Box- (2)").Select`
`Rows("1:15").Select`
`Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False`
`Rows("1:9").Select`
`Range("A9").Activate`
`Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp`
`Sheets("BioME-Box- (3)").Select`
`Rows("1:13").Select`
`Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False`
```

`Rows("1:9").Select`
    `Range("A9").Activate`
    `Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp`

Comment: What code have you tried so far? What is unsuccessful about it? (Does it throw errors, does it run but not do anything, does it do something but not what you're expecting, etc.)

Comment: Wouldn't "top 5 rows" include "A1:Z1"?

Comment: Yes it does, currently I have a really long version of the VBA set up.

Comment: current code to just remove the top rows.

Comment: Sub remove_rows()
 remove_rows Macro
      Rows("1:10").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Range("D20").Select
    Rows("1:9").Select
    Range("A9").Activate
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Sheets("BioME-Box- (2)").Select
    Rows("1:15").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Rows("1:9").Select

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are talking about Validation lists as your "drop down" lists.  If so then they might be getting their options from a another range somewhere else.  So if you delete a range that the validation lists are using then all of their options disappear.  I don't know if this is your problem.  But you can copy a validation list and paste only its value, not the whole list, this way.

```
Sub Macro1()
    Range("D3").Select '    This is the validation list
    Selection.Copy

    '   Change "SomeOtherRangeHere" to any cell you want to
    Range("SomeOtherRangeHere").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello John yes it

Comment: John, it could be getting the drop down values from a list, what I am trying to do is keep the selected values and merge all the worksheets into 1. But starting the appending of data only from A10 as A1 to A9 consists of examples of how to fill the data and what type of data

Comment: I will try to upload a sample workbook. Thank you for all the help

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.  Be sure to change mainWS to the worksheet you are copying to.  I used sheet1 but you may be using another.  In this sub it copies everything below Row 9 of all sheets and pastes them to the first available row in sheet1.

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim ws As Worksheet, mainWS As Worksheet
Dim wsLastRow As Long, mainWSlastRow As Long, wsLastCol As Long

    Set mainWS = Sheet1 ' Change this to the sheet you are copying everthing to
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        def = mainWS.Name
        abc = ws.Name
        If ws.Name <> mainWS.Name Then ' Make sure to not copy from the sheet yuo are copying to
            wsLastRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
            wsLastCol = ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count
            On Error Resume Next
            mainWSlastRow = Sheet1.Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
            If Err.Number = 91 Then
                mainWSlastRow = 1
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
            ws.Range("A10:" & Chr(wsLastCol + 64) & wsLastRow).Copy Destination:=mainWS.Range("A" & mainWSlastRow + 1)
        End If
    Next ws
    Set mainWS = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: Hello John, I tried the code, it did not throw up any error but neither did it do anything. Am not sure what is wrong?

Comment: it will only copy data from below row 9.  Is there data on the other sheets below row 9?  Also what sheet are you copying to? Sheet1, sheet2..?  Are you running the code from within a single workbook or two workbooks.  This is designed (as it is) to go through all sheets in a single workbook and copy data below row 9 on all sheets other than sheet1.  Because sheet1 is where the copied data is being placed.  It works fine for me

Comment: Try stepping through it with the debugger to see where it is not working.

Comment: After reviewing it's possible that the "MainWSLastRow =" line was throwing an error if sheet 1 is blank.  I've changed the code above to account for that.

Comment: Sorry but I had to update it again for error handling.  It should be working now